# Angular 9 interceptor not working when imported to specific component

Tags: angular, interceptor, angular-providers

[image]

Hey guys! I was trying to use an interceptor but I dont want to import it in app.module.ts since I just need it for some components. Creating some logic to avoid some urls seems to be too much work. Is it ok to provide a component with the interceptor? Is there a way to make this work? Also, our components do not have modules. We just have app.module.ts

Comment: Just for more clarification, what have you tried? Can you post a code snippet instead of a screenshot? What are the errors or expectations?

Comment: you would need to create two different modules or else why using an interceptor if you'r gonna import it in every component ?